# How to install vent cap over cement pipe?

Tags: water-heater, roof, vent, flashing

[image]

The picture attached is a cement vent pipe I found on the roof for water heater venting. Looks like the cap has been broken off, but I have no idea what was the original looks like. The diameter of the cement pipe is 4.75". The closest Lowes vent cap I found is either a 4in or a 6in Selkirk cap. But Im not sure if i get the 6 inch, are the screws going to penetrate the cement enough to get a good grip? I dont want it to be blown off in the future. What is the proper way to do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That flue pipe looks like "Transite" pipe which was used on some gas only appliances before about 1960. When I got into the heating business in the late 1960's nobody was still using it. There were better alternatives. If it is transite, it probably contains asbestos. I don't know of any caps available for use on this product. You could take a standard 6" cap and slit the bottom connection in about 6 sections and bend the slit pieces inward and use a large hose clamp to hold the cap to the old pipe. You could "GOOGLE" transite to learn about this pipe. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge! But just to be sure i get the right item. Can you provide either Homedepot or Lowes item url links for the "Bottom Connection" you stated? 
And how long is "6 sections"? The 6inch duct i found at hd is at least 2ft. But the flue pipe is only about 1.5ft. Thanks.

Comment: I also found a item called the 3 in. to 5 in. Adjustable Versa Cap, Do you think i can use this without "bottom connections"?
https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-in-to-5-in-Adjustable-Versa-Cap-3050/100396918

Comment: That versa cap should work since you said that the diameter of the flue pipe is 4.75".. Put it on  and you will have a new chimney cap. If you want the cap to be a little higher, you could add a piece of 5" round duct to the top of the old pipe but I would not worry about it. Just install the cap to the cement pipe

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Finished installing the versa cap.